# First occurrence of a positive integer using binary search

Tags: python, binary-search

I've tried to write a code that finds the first occurrence of a positive integer in a sorted array using binary search, but it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```py
def findFirstOccurrence(arr):

    (left, right) = (0, len(arr) - 1)

    result = -1

    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2

        if 0 < arr[mid]:
            result = mid
            right = mid - 1
        elif 0 > arr[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return result
```

Comment: Can you share the input and where's the issue?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help.

```py
def findFirstOccurrence(arr):
  left,right=0,len(arr)-1
  while not((left==right) or (right==left+1)):
    mid=(left+right)//2
    if arr[mid]>0:
      right=mid
    else:
      left=mid

  if arr[left]>0:
    return left
  if arr[right]>0:
    return right
  return None

print(findFirstOccurrence([-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,5,3,4,6]))
```

Output

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the lines

```python3
elif 0 > arr[mid]:
    right = mid - 1
```

If `arr[mid]` is negative, we decrease the `right` pointer — i.e. we look further to the **left**. But if the array is sorted in ascending order, then anything further to the left of a negative number is still negative, so we'll never reach a positive number and the program will fail.

What we want to do instead is look to the **right**, where the positive numbers are. The lines

```python3
else:
    left = mid + 1
```

already do that in the case that `arr[mid] == 0`. Removing the two erroneous lines would allow the case that `arr[mid] < 0` to fall through and do what we want.

Final code:

```python3
if arr[mid] > 0:
    result = mid
    right = mid - 1
else:
    left = mid + 1
```